# Determine a parameterization for the line which is tangent to the curve at t=2

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, parametric

(1) A curve is given by the function $$r(t)=(t^3 -3t^2 +2t +4)i + (13-5t)j +(t^2 -t-3)k$$

Determine a parameterization for the line which is tangent to the curve at $t=2$

I started by solving for when $t=2$, and got the vector $4i + 3j - k$

I don't know what this vector means or if this was even the correct approach. Do I need to find the vector perpendicular to this, or what should I be doing instead?

Comment: How about taking a derivative of the given function?

Comment: By plugging in $t=2$, you know the point that the tangent must go through, but you still need the direction of this tangent. You can get the direction by finding the derivative of the curve at the point $t=2$.

Answer (score 1):

The tangent vector to the curve will always point in the direction of the tangent of the curve. We obtain the tangent vector by differentiating, it is given by

$$
\mathbf{T}(t) = \dot{\mathbf{r}}(t) = (3t^2 - 6t + 2)\mathbf{i} -5\mathbf{j} +(2t -1)\mathbf{k}
$$

The direction of the line tangent to the curve at $t=2$ is then

$$
\mathbf{T}(2) = 2\mathbf{i} - 5\mathbf{j} + 3\mathbf{k}
$$

Then the line is given by

$$
\mathbf{l}(\lambda) = \lambda \mathbf{T}(2) + \mathbf{k} $$
Where $\mathbf{k}$ is fixed by the condition that $\mathbf{l}$ intersects $\mathbf{r}$ at $t=2$, so $\mathbf{k} = \mathbf{r}(2) - 2\mathbf{T}(2)$.